# the chain rule yields different results

Tags: calculus

I found this interesting equation.

Suppose there is a function $y = t^3 - 9t$

Now I want to differentiate it using chain rule in two ways

**The first way to differentiate it)**

let $u = t^3$

let $y = u -9t$

therefore $u' = 3t^2$

therefore $y'= 1-9 = -8$

hence $y' = -24t^2$

**the second way)**

let $u = t^3$

let $y = t^3 - 9t$

therefore $u' = 3t^2$

therefore $y' = 3t^2 - 9$

hence $y' = 9t^4  - 27t^2$

BUT...none of these are the correct answers - the correct one using the sum law is 3t^2 - 9. You may say that my error is "due to applying the chain rule for the wrong function. The function above is not a composite function and therefore the chain rule can't be used to differentiate it."

Yet it appears to me that it IS a composite function. It can separated into two functions;

$g(t) = t^3$

$f(t) = t-9t^{1/3}$

combined to give $f(g(t)) $

Comment: By your (second) method the derivative of $y=\sin(t^3)$ will be $3t^2\cos t$. Do you see what’s wrong?

Comment: no, I have not got to trig functions yet

Comment: Ah, I think I know where I went wrong - in both my methods, I got the wrong answers because I separated the function into the wrong constituent parts.

Comment: Write the chain rule carefully. You need $f’(g(t))\cdot g’(t)$. In method 2 you wrote $f’(t)\cdot g’(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
g(t) &= t^3, \\
f(t) &= t-9t^{1/3}, \\
y(t) &= f(g(t)) = t^3 - 9t.
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
g'(t) &= 3t^2, \\
f'(t) &= 1 - 3t^{-2/3}, \\
y'(t) &= f'(g(t))\, g'(t) \\
&= \left(1 - 3(g(t))^{-2/3} \right)(3t^2) \\
&= \left(1 - 3t^{-2} \right)(3t^2) \\
&= 3t^2 - 9. \\
\end{align}

The chain rule works for $y(t)$ as a composite function, but you must treat it as the correct composite function while applying the chain rule and you must apply the chain rule correctly.